Blazor components folder issue
I am working on a Blazor hybrid project and have a component called ArraySelector.
If I place the component in a subdirectory BaseComponents as shown below

And set

The @onclick event is not recognize and gives an error on execution.

If I copy my component in a subdirectory under components,


then the @onclick is recognized and it works.

So I wonder what could be the reason of this behavior?
What am I doing wrong?

Razor editing in VS is still really finnicky like this. Notice how the syntax highlighting is diffrent in your two images. I often have to completely close a solution and restart VS especially when moving components around.

Here is the reason of the behavior and how to correct it.
It is because the BaseComponents/ArraySelector.razor doesn’t have @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web (that’s where events like @onclick are defined, specifically in class EventHandlers). That’s because the Components/_Imports.razor file doesn’t have an effect on the folder BaseComponents. One can either add the @using to the component, or to a BaseComponents/_Imports.razor file or (probably the best option) move the _Imports.razor file to the root of the project.
